# Validate an IP and CIDR combo

Tags: php, networking, ip

I have a user submitted IP address with netmask, and I need to make sure it is valid. For instance, if the user submits: 10.113.0.0/14, I need to flag it as invalid, because the /14 block for that IP range begins with 10.112.0.0.

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Why is it invalid?  10.112.0.0 /14 has addresses from 10.112.0.0 - 10.115.255.255.

Comment: True, but 10.113.0.0 does not have a cidr of 14, because that would imply that it has 262,142 usable addresses. That would overflow the range of 10.115.255.255. 10.133.0.0 has 65,534 usable addresses, thus it is a /16.

Comment: 10.113.0.0 /14 is a valid address in the 10.112.0.0 /14 network.  So is 10.115.254.1 /14.  I think you are asking a different question.

Comment: I didn't ask how to validate of 10.113.0.0 was in the 10.112.0.0/14 network. I think you are answering a different question. I know this: run this query in postgresql: select '10.113.0.0/14'::cidr. It will error with: ERROR:  invalid cidr value: "10.113.0.0/14"
DETAIL:  Value has bits set to right of mask.

Comment: The question you wanted answered was; how to determine if an IP Address and CIDR pair represent a valid NETWORK IP address and CIDR pair.  The way to do that is to convert the IP address and CIDR to numbers, AND them and see if the resulting IP address matches the given IP address.

Comment: Above will not always work. Lets say given value is 192.168.10.0/26. The netmask has 26 bits on while the IP has no bits on in the last 4 bits. The and will result into same IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function cidrMatch at the bottom of http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/extras/incubator/library/ZendX/Whois/Adapter/Cidr.php should do what you want

Comment: That isn't quite what I was looking for, but it did provide me the math I need. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your resulting function please?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, so posting my result for googlers:

```
$ipLong = ip2long($ip);
if ( ( ($ipLong << $prefix) ^ 0) == true ) {
    //IP and prefix pair is not valid
}
```

#### Explanation

Let's evaluate 255.255.0.0/16

For ip 255.255.0.0 binary representation of long is 10000000000000000

1. `$ipLong << $prefix` Shift 16 bits to left for deleting all network ID bits.
2. `^ 0` Evaluate if any bit is set after previous operation.
3. For valid IP and prefix all bits must be unset, so if result is `true` we have invalid pair.

Comment: that didn't work fro me , can you explain your answer more

Comment: IP in binary representation is something like 10101010000. The "/4" means how much bytes you should shift to left: 1010101---0000. After the shift of the valid IP, you should have all zeros left. To the this you run `^ 0`

Answer (score 0):

Tool 'sipcalc' will help you to validate netmask and cidr.

http://www.routemeister.net/